Running PowerShell Script from Task Scheduler Fails - New-SmbMapping
I have a Powershell script that I run on our satellite locations to copy an Access db each day. All nine of our locations had this script running smoothly until I had to edit them recently. Now, if I run the script manually, it runs correctly but when the scheduled task runs it, the task completes but the script returns an error. I have the script starting a transcript while running to troubleshoot this issue. The line producing the error is:
New-SmbMapping -LocalPath 'P:' -RemotePath \123.123.123.123\SharedFile$ -Username xxxx -password xxxx
Here is the error text:
Transcript started, output file is C:\temp\problem-script.txt
New-SmbMapping : The local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource.
At E:\FOLDER\FOLDER\PS_Script.ps1:5 char:1

New-SmbMapping -LocalPath 'P:' -RemotePath \123.123.123.123\SharedFile$ ...

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SmbMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...MSFT_SmbMapping) [New-SmbMapping], 



CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1202,New-SmbMapping
New-SmbMapping : The local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource.
At E:\FOLDER\FOLDER\SharedFile.ps1:5 char:1

New-SmbMapping -LocalPath 'P:' -RemotePath \123.123.123.123\SharedFile$ ...

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SmbMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...MSFT_SmbMapping) [New-SmbMapping], CimE
xception
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1202,New-SmbMapping




I have the task running as "SYSTEM" and whether user is logged in or not, with highest privileges.
Any help would be appreciated.

SYSTEM user cannot connect to network shares, so that's going to fail for sure. The error would suggest that there's already a mapping to the same server, but with different credentials, that established, and as such, it will only work if you specify the same credentials for the new connection or break the other connection. Another option is to connect to a different ip or hostname, even if that leads to the same server.

Thanks for the insight. I do specify the credentials to use in the script. I was under the impression that would be sufficient, but maybe that is not accurate. The machines I am copying the file from are not AD-joined so I can't run the task under that same user credentials since I am running it from one of our servers that is AD-joined. I also have the identical script working on most of my locations. When I run manually, I don't get the remembered connection error. This one has me stumped.

Its a precaution. The SYSTEM user can only do things on the local computer, not any authentication on a network resource. Just run it under a local AD user or administrator and save the credentials, and it should work, even if that local user is not the same as the credentials used in the script.

If it's domain joined and the UNC share path is also joined to the same domain, you can access the UNC path with SYSTEM without mapping it as a drive letter though. The <computername>$ would need permission to the share and the NTFS folder ACLs both in order to do this. If they are not domain joined or on separate domains, running as SYSTEM won't work unless you have access wide open but I've never tried it. In domain environments, this is how startup scripts work referencing UNC if Domain Computers or the AD computer object has explicit access.

A workaround I vaguely recall in a workgroup environment I set up something was to have local server and local computer account on each machine with the same username and password set and ensure it's configured NTFS and share permissions wise with the same credential across the systems but it did not run as SYSTEM and it was not a scheduled task but if you test and that will work, it may suffice. Quick thoughts only and thus the comments in case it helps.

Thanks to both of you for the comments! Once I changed the task to run as my admin account instead of system, the task is completing successfully!
